# Development server is not starting and getting no response

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I am a beginner for django web development. Initially i created a project and an app. When i try to run the django server using the `python manage.py runserver` command it loads for sometime and i get no response.

I am using Pycharm 2019 community edition

Comment: There should be some error with it ?

Comment: No i did not get any error for that. I am trying to run the development server using windows powershell

Comment: What do you mean, "no response"? What exactly do you see?

Comment: nothing. It does'nt show me error also.

Answer (score 0):

You mention you are using PyCharm. Can you use your terminal window within PyCharm (normally at the bottom, possible toggle view with Alt+F12). In that terminal window try typing `python manage.py runserver` and see if that gives you an error.

Comment: Thank you 'AMG' let me try that once.

Comment: Thanks it works. But the Pycharm crashes unexpectedly. It needs restart everytime it crashes

Comment: @IswarianSG I would suggest you to use command line initially then switch to pycharm

Comment: Pycharm is my IDE of choice for sure, but it does do well if you've got a good amount of memory in your machine. Much depends on your own setup. If using a virtual environment for your app PyCharm manages so much for you and using the tools within the IDE save me time (package installs, environment variables, manage.py tasks etc).